# Sonos integration with anonymous access and the application registration form

Tags: sonos

I/we at www.dr.dk are working on a Sonos integration with the bare minimum functionality. This means that we wish to apply anonymous access in this first version of our Sonos integration.

In the API documentation

https://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/289#toc0

is says 'Finally, you can decide not to use any authentication, also knows as anonymous access. ...'

Which we read as an option to not to implement authentication endpoints like 'GetAppLink(...)' etc.

So now we have teste our service and it appears to work fine, as far as we know. Therefore we have now started to fill out the application registration form.
In the registration form we find the following required fields regarding authentication as depicted in the image below

[Screenshot from the application registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfRIH.png)

As we see it these fields are related to authentication and seems somewhat confusing to us. So with our logic - anonymous authentication means that no test accounts or customer care accounts are needed etc.

So the question is. What are we missing ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just mark those as N/A for each of the fields.